Update the dynamic DLL version in Windows application
I have an external 3rd party DLL that is installed in this path in my machine:
C:\ProgramFiles\innuity\secure.DLL

I want to refer to the DLL in my Windows application and set as Copy Local = false. And I need to publish the package and deploy to the server.
The server also has this path:
C:\ProgramFiles\innuity\secure.DLL

but if I set the Copy Local = false and publish the package, I can successfully publish the setup, but it seems when I install the setup on the server, when I access the functionality of the DLL, it throws an error "assembly not found".
C:\ProgramFiles\innuity\secure.DLL: this DLL version will keep on changing when we get the latest updates from the third party.
Set as copy local = false and it throws an "assembly is not found" error.

When it works locally not having that dll in your output path. How does your app find that dll? Do you have "C:\ProgramFiles\innuity" in your path settings?

yes. i do have this path in my local as well server : C:\ProgramFiles\innuity
